# Aggregate all previous rows for a specific time difference

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Spark DataFrame with the following entries:

```
| order id | time             | amt |
| 1        | 2017-10-01 12:00 | 100 |
| 2        | 2017-10-01 15:00 | 100 |
| 3        | 2017-10-01 17:00 | 100 |
| 4        | 2017-10-02 16:00 | 100 |
| 5        | 2017-10-02 23:00 | 100 |
```

I want to add a column `amount_prev_24h` that has, for each `order id`, the sum of `amt` for all orders in the last 24 hours.

```
| order id | time             | amt | amt_24h
| 1        | 2017-10-01 12:00 | 100 | 0       
| 2        | 2017-10-01 15:00 | 100 | 100
| 3        | 2017-10-01 17:00 | 100 | 200
| 4        | 2017-10-02 16:00 | 100 | 100
| 5        | 2017-10-02 23:00 | 100 | 100
```

How would I go about doing it?

Comment: For each order by? Is not clear.

Comment: Edited. Hope its clearer

Comment: Order 4, shouldn't be 0 for amt_24h?

Comment: order 3 in less than 24 hour apart from order 4 right ?

Comment: Ah ok, now I understood

Comment: @Saurabh7 you can checkout my answer at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47170867/how-to-get-the-count-for-each-row-before-half-hour-period-having-the-value-of-1/47174455#47174455)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pyspark code and similar to scala API.

```
df = df.withColumn('time_uts', unix_timestamp('time', format='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'))
df = df.withColumn('amt_24h', sum('amt').over(Window.orderBy('time_uts').rangeBetween(-24 * 3600, -1))).fillna(0, subset='amt_24h')
```

I hope this may help you.